# Diacritic Letters are mistreated by Rest Client

Tags: rest, grails, tomcat7

I'm using `rest:0.8` to connect my main Grails project to another Grails project that serves as a report generator using this line of code:

```
Map<String, String> adminConfigService = [
    webURL: "http://192.168.20.21:8080/oracle-report-service/generate",
    ...
]

Map params = [
    ...
    name: "Iñigo",
    ...
]

withHttp(uri: adminConfigService.webURL) {
    html = get(query: params)
}
```

And then the receiving REST client will process that data. Running the two projects in my local machine works fine. Although when I deploy the `war` file of the report generator to our tomcat server, it converts the letter `"ñ"` to `"├â┬æ"`, so the name `"Iñigo"` is treated as `"I├â┬æigo"`.

Since the Report Generator project works fine when run on my local machine, does that means I need to change some `conf` files on my Tomcat Server? What setting file do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like encoding issue.

1. Check `Config.groovy`:

> grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"

2. Check file's encoding of controllers and services where you use rest:0.8.
3. Check [URIEncoding](https://struts.apache.org/docs/how-to-support-utf-8-uriencoding-with-tomcat.html) in tomcat's `server.xml` (must be UTF-8).
   Also try to set `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` (in connector, like URIEncoding parameter).
4. Do you save this data to the database? If that so, check your `DataSource.groovy` url parameter:

> url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?**characterEncoding=utf8**"

Also check encoding and collation of you table and fields in the database.